# How do I install all packages that are included in Anaconda?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, requirements

I'm attending a course which advises us to use anaconda. Because of this, there is no requirements.txt, but rather only packages included in anaconda are required.

Since I already have a python environment set up, I dont want to install another python. Is there a requirements.txt that installs all packages from anaconda?

Comment: I do not think it exists but you can try to create your own from the [list of available packages](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/pkg-docs) for your OS and python. I would install the packages as needed though.

Comment: That's what I did. The list is longer than expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/pkg-docs when you select the desired python version and target OS and architecture you will see all available packages and there is a column with the packages that are included by default in the anaconda installer.

For [example](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py2.7_win-64) python 2.7 win 64bits

You could make a python script to check for `<i class="fa fa-check"></i>` and make a txt of the default packages.

**EDIT:**
Adding another way I suggested in comments below.

*Alternative method:*
Using online regex web services

Step 1: copy the html table removing for simpler regex the unnecesary tags and keeping the tr td tags like so

`<tr>
    <td><a href="https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-nb-extensions-meta-config">_nb_ext_conf</a></td>
    <td>0.4.0</td>
    <td>A configuration metapackage for enabling Anaconda-bundled jupyter extensions / BSD</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>`

Step 2: Paste it into a regex web like [regexr](https://regexr.com/) and craft your regex, I managed to come up real quick with this one: `<td><a.+">(.+)<\/a><\/td>\s+<td>.+<\/td>\s+<td>.+<\/td>\s+<td><i.+check.+<\/td>` im pretty sure it can be improved but works.

Step 3: get your list by specifying how you want to output your capture group: `$1 \n` $1 is your capture group and \n is newline, so you would get a list of packages like so:

`alabaster 
anaconda-client 
anaconda-navigator 
anaconda-project 
asn1crypto 
astroid 
astropy 
babel`

Comment: I guess you are correct with this. But since the list ist unexpectedly long, I think I will go with Goyo's approach of installing everything that is needed manually.

Comment: You could also use online RegEx webpages for a faster (and lazy) way to get the list instead of making a python script.

First you copy the html table from the web page source, then use a webservice like [regexr](https://regexr.com/) to get the list.  I will update my answer to reflect this suggestion